# What means the phrase "Record what you are drawn to"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "Record what you are drawn to", can you explain it properly? The entire extract is the following:

> You are an explorer your mission is to document and observe the world around you as you've never seen it before. Take notes. Collect things you find on your travels. Document your findings. Notice patterns. Copy. Trace. Focus on one thing at a time. Record what you are drawn to.

Comment: Generally, we ask for [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like the surrounding context or a larger portion of the text, in case the meaning is not clear.

Comment: What part exactly is not clear to you?  More context would help a lot, but I suspect *record* means "put down in concrete form", like writing something down or making a recording.  *to be drawn to something* means to be attracted by it.

Comment: The obscure part was the meaning of the expression "drawn to". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As you explore the world, you will come across many things. You are being asked to look upon the, afresh. You will find some of those things particularly interesting; they will attract your attention. You will be **drawn to** them. Keep a record of what those things are.

(I disagree with @Andrew's answer. The instructions make clear that you have to pay attention to everything you come across. You are simply being asked, as you make your notes, to keep track of which things you found particularly appealing among all the things in the world you're exploring.)

Answer (score 1):

> [Do] what you are drawn to

This idiomatic expression simply suggest that you "do" the thing that attracts you the most.  If, for example, you are an aspiring writer, I might advise:

> Write about what you are drawn to.

meaning that you should stick with writing about the topics which excite you, capture your interest, etc.  Otherwise you're more likely to be frustrated and quit.

The exercise in your example tells you to imagine yourself an explorer of a new world.  There are far too many things for you to document them all, so instead *focus* on those which you find most interesting.